# JQuery animation not working. possibly incorrect syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

im very lost as to why this basic JQuery code isnt working, i just want this text to move 500px to the right when the button is clicked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0   Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src = "jquery-2.0.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('button').click(function(){
    $('div').animate({right:'500px'}, fast);
 });
});

</script>
</head>

<body>

<div style = "position: absolute; top: 100px;">
    Test Box
</div>
<button>click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does the Javascript console in your browser show any errors?

Comment: no, it just doenst work

Comment: did you try using an int value instead of `fast`? see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k9Sve/)

Comment: OP is lying about errors in the console, because `fast` is undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the part :  `$('div').animate({right:'500px'}, fast);` fast must be :  `"fast"`
 
it worked for me!

Answer (score 4):

Right here, the code is written like 'fast' was a var:

```
     $('div').animate({right:'500px'}, fast);
```

The "speed" parameter should be in quotes, like this:

```
     $('div').animate({right:'500px'}, 'fast');
```

That should do it..

Answer (score 2):

The word `fast` needs to be be in quotes. Or pass in `int` value for time in milliseconds.

http://jsfiddle.net/Buwn9/

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('div').animate({right:'500px'}, 'fast');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').animate({right:'500px'}, 'fast');
```

in this case, effect should be a string, we can give in numeric also as below

```
$('div').animate({right:'500px'}, 500);
```